# How to add 1 background picture behind all list items in linear layout - android

Tags: android

How to add 1 background picture behind all list items in linear layout (add picture in red selected rectangle)

[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="100px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
    android:layout_marginRight="20px"
    android:layout_marginTop="5px"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="100px" >
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: If any of the answers helped you out, please accept the one that did the most as a correct one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can you RelativeLayout instead of the LinearLayout in the view that contains your ListView. It will let you overlap views.

Comment: can you write some example here pls?

Comment: post XML code of the view these views are in and ill see what I can do.

Comment: post the XML where your ListView is

Answer (score 0):

You can set drawable as background for listview in xml file using,

```
 android:background="@drawable/yourImage"
```

then set background of all the views in row xml file as transperent to make list view background visible.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"> <!--set to transperent -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginRight="20px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent" > <!--set to transperent -->
    </ImageView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="100px" 
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"> <!--set to transperent -->
    </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps.